# How to detect that after patch value, form data has been changed or not in angular6?

Tags: angular5, angular-reactive-forms

In my app, I did `patchValue` to my `formControl`, when user click on next/submit button, I want to detect that, Is form value has been changed or not?

**Tried**

- ```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    alert("Change found");
  }
  ```
- ```
  this.partnerForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    console.log("[partnerForm valueChanges subscribe]", val);
  });
  ```

**Reason why I need this?**

- I need to call API when form value has any change otherwise I just need to navigate the user to next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form.valueChanges doesn't work after patch value.
so for a detect change, you can compare your objects:

```
let valueChange = (JSON.stringify(oldObj) === JSON.stringify(currentObj))
```

it will return true or false according to your value changes.

Comment: This is a hack. Maybe reactive form has an api for this

Answer (score 0):

first, get your control as `FormControl`
then check `yourFormControl.hasChanged()`
this returns true if the value of your form control gets changed

Comment: Can you please share any example So it'll be more helpful for me as well as others.